# Timex3 datetime parsing and conversion

Tags: node.js, datetime, parsing, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

We are using Language Understanding serivce from Microsoft (LUIS) that allows us to extract dates and times from user input.

Example string

```
"my vacation is on 2019-10-01 at 3pm"
```

extracts to a Timex3 object: `2019-10-01T03:00pm` which is great, but if datetime is not fully recognized then timex has it's own format that I'm not sure how to parse.

Timex supports ambigous data, such as:

```
XXXX-05-02 - May 2nd, any year
XXXX-05-02,XXXX-05-05,P3D - May 2nd to 5th
```

This format is great, but I'm not sure how to parse all possible combinations. I'm trying to get user input to schedule reminders. So, for XXXX-05-02 I want to send them a reminder once a year on May 2nd. Most schedulers support CRON format, so ideally I would like to be able to convert TIMEX to CRON but I cannot find any info on how to do this. The only documents that are available are:
Timex3 specification:
http://www.timeml.org/tempeval2/tempeval2-trial/guidelines/timex3guidelines-072009.pdf
and Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2

Answer (score 2):

So in the BotBuilder-Samples repo on GitHub, on the C# side, there's a sample with some explanation given in the readme regarding how to handle TIMEX [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/40.timex-resolution).

Visiting the recognizers repo directly, where the TIMEX expression library is contained, you can also find examples of how to use the regonizers library to handle TIMEX in JavaScript as well, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/JavaScript/samples).

The examples given in the links above do not convert to CRON, but allow you to do the following (as specified in C# samples readme):

> - Parse TIMEX expressions to give you the properties contained there in.
> - Generate TIMEX expressions based on setting raw properties.
> - Generate natural language from the TIMEX expression. (This is logically the reverse of the Recognizer.)
> - Resolve TIMEX expressions to produce example date-times. (This produces the same result as the Recognizer (and therefore LUIS)).
> - Evaluate TIMEX expressions against constraints such that new more precise TIMEX expressions are produced.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to convert the normalized timex value to your cron format?

Ideal case would be find normalized value patterns and extract information to parse in your format. In TIMEX3 guidelines, there are four types of TIMEX type mentioned which have their specific patterns for normalized value.

- If a *date* type is matched, you can extract year/month/day from the date value
- If a *time* type is matched, you can additionally extract time in hour/minute manner
- If a *duration* type is matched, beginning and ending time point of an event is also found.

In some cases, they have under specified values like "XXXX" in stead of a full year. Then based on the context or at least from current reference date this value can be converted to some absolute value.